# jQuery animation problems

Tags: jquery, html, css

What i'm attempting to do is on load up have the logo in the middle of the screen, then after 3 seconds animate it to the top of the screen and have the rest of the content fade in.

Here is my jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#slider-wrapper').hide();
            $("#logo").animate({ 
                bottom:'+=250px'
              }, 1500 );
            $('#slider-wrapper').fadeIn(2000);
            $('#slider').nivoSlider();
        });
</script>
```

So slider-wrapper is (at the moment) all of the content i want to fade in.

Can anyone think of the problem so far? At the moment, the logo isnt moving at all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your `logo` has an `absolute`, `relative` or `fixed` position, otherwise `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right` style attributes will have no effect.

Also, to have it happen in the order you want, you need to do the fade in the [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) callback (so it runs when the animation completes), like this:

```
$('#slider-wrapper').hide();
$("#logo").animate({ bottom:'+=250px' }, 1500, function() {
  $('#slider-wrapper').fadeIn(2000);
});
```